# Bootstrap navbar trigger right side wrapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use a twitter bootstrap navbar.

I want to have the left side of the navbar going over the right side **and/or** to be able to trigger when the right side is wrapping to keep a one line navbar.

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3AlXLDz6adRbRZUuO2lQ?p=preview).

I tried different solutions:

- Adding `<div style="overflow:hidden">` tag to wrap the `<ul class="navbar-right">` tag. It didn't work.
- This [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/f-9dT8wqszs). Not what I want.
- This post on [Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9566). I don't know how many *Link* the navbar have, it depends on the user rights. Not a solution.

Any other solution?

Comment: Is your issue the line-wrapping or the positioning of navbar-right elements?

Comment: My issue is that the all navbar-right element is wrapping in some middle size screen (depending on the number of link elements). I'd like to know when the navbar becomes 2 lines, whatever the number of navbar-right link elements is. Then I could compact or hide those elements to keep a one line navbar. I use AngularJs maybe it can help.

Comment: When the navbar becomes two lines varies according to how many links you have and how many characters each of those links has in it's name

Comment: I know. Do you have a solution to avoid wrapping by hiding or compacting those links? (Again without knowing how many links are there)